# Practical substitution of a $\frac{0}{0}$ form

Tags: limits

I have to evaluate the following mean square error:

$$ \frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^T s_t^2 = \frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^T \left(\frac{a_t - b_t}{b_t}\right)^2$$

Suppose now that for a given $t$, we have that $a_t = b_t = 0$. This means that $s_t = \frac{0}{0}$. I was wondering if it is a good practice to substitute $\frac{0}{0}$ with $0$ since in general I know that

$$a_t = b_t = c \Rightarrow s_t = 0$$

What do you thing about this substitution?

Comment: In some sense you are correct but not for the right reason. First of all : $\frac00 \ne 0$. However because it is undefined, you could omit them from the sum in which case it is the same as adding zeros.

Comment: @user88595 many thanks! Do you think that I should also correct the $\frac{1}{T}$ factor in order to take into account the "skipped" terms I'm not summing up?

Comment: I wouldn't change it as $a_t = b_t = 0$ means there is no error so it's "good". By changing $\frac1T$, you'll be totally ignoring the point. That's my opinion but I am not the best person to ask about MSE I'm afraid.

Comment: ok, your have been really precious!

Comment: Computing these relative errors when $b_t$ could be zero seems like it is a bad idea. What if $a_t\ne0\land b_t=0$ ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust good point. How would you proceed in this case?

Comment: I would question the use of relative errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noted, the relative error misbehaves when the true value is zero or very close to it. In the  [Computational Science thread](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/3362) one can find several practical suggestions on this topic, including an algorithm proposed by Donald Knuth himself.  One simple fix is to recognize that relative errors of 100% or 4000% mean about the same: the result is way off. So, one can take $|a_t-b_t|/(|a_t|+|b_t|)$, which conveniently takes values in $[0,1]$ only. One should still check the denominator for zeroness; but now the denominator being zero means $a_t=b_t=0$, so the result should be zero in this case.

However, for your purposes it's probably important to maintain quadratic dependence on $a_t$. If this is the case, and you want the error to be relative to size, I would minimize 
$$\frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^T \left(\frac{a_t - b_t}{|b_t| + \epsilon}\right)^2$$ 
where $\epsilon$ is chosen after exploratory analysis of your $b_t$ values.

Comment: thank you very much! Your proposal with $\epsilon$ sounds really good!